# OutOfMemoryError after migrating to spring 6 / hibernate 6 / spring boot 3 with multiple datasources, caused by TransactionManagement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

can someone help me please: I trying to migrate huge java project from hibernate 5, spring 5 & spring boot 2 to hibernate 6, spring 6 & spring boot 3 but I'm stuck with an OutOfMemory exception that seems to be a circular dependency problem, caused by @PostConstruct annotation.

Here is my **ApplicationConfiguration** class (Class and methods names was changed and useless code for this topic was removed):

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(
        excludeName = { 
            "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration"
        }
    )
    @ComponentScan( ... )
    @PropertySource
    @EnableCaching
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @Configuration
    public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    
        @Primary
        @Autowired
        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                                             MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
                                                             CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl) {
            
            // Some code: Creation of LocalSessionFactoryBean for primary datasource
        }
    
        @Bean
        @Autowired
        @Primary
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
                    
            // Some code: Creation of primary transaction manager
        }
    }
```

Here is **MyCustomDAO** class

```
    public class MyCustomDAO {
    
        @Autowired(required = false)
        @Qualifier("transactionManager")
        @Lazy
        protected HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager;
    
        @Transactional
        public void myCustomMethod() {
        
            // Some transactional code
    
        }
    }
```

Last, but not least, **MyCustomService** class with a `@PostConstruct` method that throw Exception:

```
    @Service
    public class MyCustomService {
       
        @Autowired
        private MyCustomDAO myCustomDAO;
    
        @PostConstruct
        public void updateStatus() {
            
            // since 'myCustomMethod' is transactional, it need a transaction
            // then throw an OutOfMemoryException
            myCustomDAO.myCustomMethod();
    
        }
    
    }
```

I faced the following error:

> `Error creating bean with name 'myCustomService': Invocation of init method failed` (begin of the message)
> and `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` (end of the message)

```
12/04/23 13:28:01 demolocal-i10_demo   [main] ERROR t.i.SpringBootApplicationLauncher - Error creating bean with name 'myCustomService': Invocation of init method failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myCustomService ': Invocation of init method failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1754)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
    at stackoverflow.example.SpringBootApplicationLauncher.initialize(SpringBootApplicationLauncher.java:335)
    at stackoverflow.example.SpringBootApplicationLauncher.main(SpringBootApplicationLauncher.java:152)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in stackoverflow.example.config.ApplicationConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'transactionManager' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in stackoverflow.example.config.ApplicationConfiguration: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:548)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:505)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702)
    at stackoverflow.example.society.MyCustomDAO$$SpringCGLIB$$1.myCustomMethod()
    at stackoverflow.example.accountinggeneral.MyCustomService.lambda$0(MyCustomService.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1092)
    at stackoverflow.example.accountinggeneral.MyCustomService.updateStatus(MyCustomService.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:192)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in stackoverflow.example.config.ApplicationConfiguration: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray0(Unsafe.java:1382)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(Unsafe.java:1375)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.newArray(StringConcatHelper.java:494)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.simpleConcat(StringConcatHelper.java:421)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeStatic(DirectMethodHandle$Holder)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/0x0000000800c04400.invoke(LambdaForm$MH)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.Invokers$Holder.linkToTargetMethod(Invokers$Holder)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.logSqlAst(SqlTreePrinter.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translateSelect(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:828)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.createLoadPlan(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.prepare(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.prepareLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3332)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3326)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:894)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:913)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:612)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$461/0x0000000800f44b08.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)

12/04/23 13:28:01 demolocal-i10_demo   [main] ERROR t.i.SpringBootApplicationLauncher - Error creating bean with name 'myCustomService': Invocation of init method failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myCustomService ': Invocation of init method failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1754)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
    at stackoverflow.example.SpringBootApplicationLauncher.initialize(SpringBootApplicationLauncher.java:335)
    at stackoverflow.example.SpringBootApplicationLauncher.main(SpringBootApplicationLauncher.java:152)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in stackoverflow.example.config.ApplicationConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'transactionManager' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in stackoverflow.example.config.ApplicationConfiguration: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:548)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:505)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702)
    at stackoverflow.example.society.MyCustomDAO$$SpringCGLIB$$1.myCustomMethod()
    at stackoverflow.example.accountinggeneral.MyCustomService.lambda$0(MyCustomService.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1092)
    at stackoverflow.example.accountinggeneral.MyCustomService.updateStatus(MyCustomService.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:192)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in stackoverflow.example.config.ApplicationConfiguration: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray0(Unsafe.java:1382)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(Unsafe.java:1375)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.newArray(StringConcatHelper.java:494)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.simpleConcat(StringConcatHelper.java:421)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeStatic(DirectMethodHandle$Holder)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH/0x0000000800c04400.invoke(LambdaForm$MH)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.Invokers$Holder.linkToTargetMethod(Invokers$Holder)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.SqlTreePrinter.logSqlAst(SqlTreePrinter.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translateSelect(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:828)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.createLoadPlan(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.prepare(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.prepareLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3332)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3326)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:894)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:913)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:612)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$461/0x0000000800f44b08.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
```

Notice that if I put `SpringApplication.setLazyInitialization(true)`, it works, also none of my webservice is available. But @PostConstruct method is not called until bean is created so I guess it is a circular dependency problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I finally fixed it** by replacing all @ManyToOne fetchtype with LAZY and changing some configuration.

so, this:

```
@ManyToOne
private MyObject myObjectReference
```

became:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private MyObject myObjectReference
```

(I have 1641 `@ManyToOne` replaced by `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`)

I Also changed my ApplicationConfiguration class: instead of using `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and `HibernateTransactionManager`, I use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `JpaTransactionManager`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
    excludeName = { 
        "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration"
    }
)
@ComponentScan( ... )
@PropertySource
@EnableCaching
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                                         MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
                                                         CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl) {
        
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);     
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan); 

        Properties hibernateProperties = hibernateProperties();
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    @Primary
    public TransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

I also changed MyCustomDAO to use EntityManager instead of HibernateTransactionManager:

```
public class MyCustomDAO {

    @PersistenceContext 
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void myCustomMethod() {
    
        // Some transactional code

    }
}
```

It works now.
I think when hibernate trying to create requests at runtime for CRUD operations, OneToOne and ManyToOne not Lazy fetched is included into requests so when there is many foreign key deeply/circular linked (Ex: TableA -> TableB -> TableC -> TableA), requests generated became so big or maybe with an infinite recursion (caused by circular Join) that an OutOfMemoryEdxception is raised

Comment: That is correct answer.  Default fetch type for ManyToOne annotation is EAGER, therefore if you have a lot of classes with a lot of ManyToOne annotated relationships you might definitely end up trying to download half or the whole database in one request.
That is why it is very import to think about those relationships through annotations or make additional methods for projections where you could specify which classes should be pulled in your query or use a NamedEntityGraph.